# Why and how Adobe Acrobat DC changes files?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

1. I open a `.pdf` file with "Adobe Acrobat DC" by double-clicking on it in Windows Explorer. It is a blood analysis document, not meant to be edited. It is not a form.
2. I close the viewer with "Alt+F4", and to my astonishment the application asks if I want to save the changes I made? I did nothing. Watched the screen with my MARK-1 eyeballs then pressed "Alt+F4". That is all.

Questions

1. What changes are being made to my PDF?
2. How can I tell "Adobe Acrobat DC" to open my files in read-only?
3. Opinionated: What SW should I use If I want quality viewing and I am not interested in editing at all?

(Windows 10, Adobe Acrobat DC "how I see the version?", but fresh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the PDF was created by non-Adobe software, when Adobe
sees something in the PDF that it doesn't like or is non-standard and
decides to "fix" it, therefore setting the whole document to become
modified.

I can't answer the rest of the question, but I can certainly do the
opinionated part : I like the fast and free
[Foxit PDF Reader](https://www.foxit.com/pdf-reader/).